# Cannot run Emacs ERT tests interactively

Tags: unit-testing, emacs, elisp, ert

I'm trying to run an Emacs ert test interactively, but it doesn't run.
I'm following the [Emacs ERT guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ert/Introduction.html#Introduction) to run this example test:

```
(require 'ert)

(ert-deftest pp-test-quote ()
  "Tests the rendering of `quote' symbols in `pp-to-string'."
  (should (equal (pp-to-string '(quote quote)) "'quote"))
  (should (equal (pp-to-string '((quote a) (quote b))) "('a 'b)\n"))
  (should (equal (pp-to-string '('a 'b)) "('a 'b)\n")))
```

Executing this test from the buffer with <kbd>M-x ert RET t RET</kbd> will output:

```
Selector: t
Passed:  0
Failed:  0
Skipped: 0
Total:   0/0

Started at:   2016-03-16 21:15:10+0100
Finished.
Finished at:  2016-03-16 21:15:10+0100
```

But it works if is executed from the console (in batch mode):

```
$ emacs -batch -l ert -l test.el -f ert-run-tests-batch-and-exit
Running 1 tests (2016-03-16 21:35:26+0100)
   passed  1/1  pp-test-quote

Ran 1 tests, 1 results as expected (2016-03-16 21:35:26+0100)
```

I'm using emacs 24.5.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you loaded (or otherwise evaluated) the test definition?

Comment: Yes, if I evaluate the buffer, tests will run even interactively. I've asked this question because I've believed that, when executing ert, it would have "auto evaluated" the current buffer before execution.

Comment: To my knowledge, `ert` doesn't do anything like that. It assumes that all tests have been evaluated beforehand. However, if this is what you want, you can easily write a wrapper function that first evaluates the current buffer, then calls `ert`.

Comment: You're right, I've checked the ert maual and it says: _You can run the tests that are currently defined in your Emacs with the command M-x ert RET t RET_. So my assumption was totally wrong, and I surely will write a wrapper function to automate this. If you write a real answer, I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run a test case, you must first define it, either by loading the file or by evaluating the buffer. The `ert` command does not do this automatically.

Of course, you can easily define your own function that evaluates the current buffer and runs `ert`.